# android 4.0 device attach usb storage drive simply list files/directory

Tags: android

The idea is simple:

Attach a USB pendrive with music (mp3) files and let android 4.0 access it.
For example to stream the music.

First of all:

- Using eclipse android File Explorer I see the mounted /mnt/USB0/ with all the files
- Using the x86 emulator ALT+F1 df command I can see /mnt/USB0
- Using the x86 emulator ALT+F1 ls /mnt/USB0 give me a list of the files
- The app has the correct permissions to access the devices

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- When I attach the pendrive the app ask for the permission and I give it.

  ```
  if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)){
     Log.d("USB","permission OKE");
     if(device instanceof UsbDevice){
         test(mUsbManager,device);
     }
  }

  void test(UsbManager mUsbManager, UsbDevice device){
      UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
  UsbDeviceConnection connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device); 
          if(connection.claimInterface(intf, true)){

      Log.d("open","YES OPENS WORKS");    

      // TRYING THINGS AT THIS PLACE

      try {
      //  String line;
      //  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls /mnt/USB0");
       // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );         
      //  while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
      //      Log.d("read",line);
      //  }
      //  in.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d("command error:",e.getMessage());
      }

      connection.releaseInterface(intf);
  }else{
      Log.d("open","cannot claim interface");
  }

  connection.close();
  ```

  }

Solutions that don't work with the facts above

- Using the app Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls /mnt/USB0"); gives me nothing
- Using Mtp don't work
- Using new File("/mnt/USB0") gives me nothing